# The best "attributive" adjective describing someone or something that has to take its turn to do something? Can "Due" be attributive?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, adjectives

Let's say three people, A and B and C, must take turn to roll a die.

Is it idiomatic and correct to say

> The **due** candidate rolls the die either on the table or on the ground depending on the previous person's result. If the previous ended up in a number lower than 4, the **due** candidate would roll on the table. Otherwise, it would roll on the ground.

To me, "due" as the **attributive adjective** sounds unfamiliar. My quick google search kind of indicates that as well. Yet, I am not very sure about it.

The issue is that, I like the **imperative connotation** that "due" carries with it.

I mean I can think of "present" or "current" but, they just don't impart the same connotation (I think).

Comment: The singular is "a **die**."  *Dice* is plural: one die, two dice.

Comment: From my own memories of instructions for games, I would expect _the player whose turn it is_. A candidate is someone standing in an election, or applying for a job.

Comment: You could use "next" or "new" to indicate you're changing who is rolling, or "current" or "active". "Candidate" seems a bit odd (unless you're rolling to try and gain admission to something, someone playing a game is not a candidate). It's hard without knowing more context.